# Files App View Controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, file-management, files-app

In Pages, Numbers, and Keynote 3.3 for iOS, Apple has done away with its custom file manager and instead uses the a version of the iOS 11 Files App to allow the user to choose and save files within the applications,

The Files-like document picker User Interface on Pages and Keynote 3.3 for iOS 11:
[image: pages]
[image: keynote]

Is this a publicly available view controller that developers can implement in 3rd-Party Applications?

Apple mentions in a user support document that these apps "work together" to present this view. Link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208077

Comment: Isn't that a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy If it is, then how did they make it the root view controller of the app? Isn't UIDocumentPickerViewController usually presented from another View Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [UIDocumentBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller).

As far as "how did they make it the root view controller of the app? Isn't [it] usually presented from another View Controller?"

Check this page: [Adding a Document Browser to Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/system_view_controllers/adding_a_document_browser_to_your_app).

> Always assign the document browser as your app's root view controller.
>   Don't place the document browser in a navigation controller, tab bar,
>   or split view, and don't present the document browser modally.

There are a lot of useful resources on that page, but a lot seems to hinge on your app being "Document Based" ([About Document-Based Applications in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

Comment: It's not the successor of the picker view controller. The picker is alive and kicking. It's a different use case: if you want to replace the start screen of your app, where you pick which document to edit, use the browser. If you want to choose a document to import (e.g. import an image into a document), use the picker.